# Helicon URL rewrite on IIS6

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, iis-6, isapi-rewrite

I have a website on classic ASP and would like to rewrite URLs for a news page, e.g. my current URL for the page is

```
www.example.com/article.asp?art_id=1001
```

this article id (1001) has a headline like `"hello urlrewrite method"`, now I would like to rewrite that URL to display like

```
www.example.com/20110501122343/hello-urlrewrite-method
(domain name+dateandtime+headline)
```

I am using [Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/). Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to use URL rewriting to turn `www.test.com/article.asp?art_id=1001` into `www.test.com/20110501122343/hello-urlrewrite-method`? This is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use mapfiles as described in Helicon's FAQ.